# How do I graph one column of a tibble versus all other columns quickly?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, tidyverse, tibble

I have a tibble with a year column and several other variable in the other columns. I would like to create some plots over time using ggplot2 where all other columns are plotted against time. Is there a way to do this easily without creating all the plots manually? Below is some example code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gridExtra)

temp <- tibble(
  num = 1:10,
  v = num +num ^ 2,
  w = num ^ 2,
  z = num  + 3
)

temp

p1 <- ggplot(temp, aes(x = num, y = v)) +
  geom_point() + labs(y = "v")

p2 <- ggplot(temp, aes(x = num, y = w)) +
  geom_point() + labs(y = "w")

p3 <- ggplot(temp, aes(x = num, y = z)) +
  geom_point() + labs(y = "z")

grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
```

The tibble I'm actually working with has between 5 and 15 columns as I'm exploring the data and changing things around.

So is there a quick way to do this without creating the plots individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
temp %>%
  tidyr::gather(variable, value, -num) %>%
  ggplot(aes(num, value)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~variable, ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
setdiff(names(temp), "num") %>% 
  map(~ ggplot(temp, aes_string("num", .x)) + 
     geom_point() + labs(y=.x)) %>% 
  grid.arrange(grobs=., ncol=3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! It does work, and produces pretty much the same thing as the solution proposed by @RoyalTS . His was just a bit easier to interpret how it works based on my experience.

Comment: @RoyalTS's answer uses faceting, which creates a single plot with multiple panels. My answer creates three separate plots and lays them out together with `grid.arrange`. `map` just takes care of iterating over the columns to create the separate plots. `map` is a `tidyverse` function that is analogous to `lapply` from base R.

Comment: I did not know that! Thanks for the little tidbit of knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package `GGally` for the exploratory data analysis.

```
library(GGally)
ggpairs(data = temp)
```

Comment: This solution does work after a fashion, though it gives more information than I need and it's not immediate how to interpret everything. Though I will definitely remember this for future analysis! Thanks!